# ConcurentModificationException while adding items in a map

Tags: java, java-8

I am facing java.util.ConcurrentModificationException while adding items to an existing list corresponding to a key

Here is my code

```
final Map<String, List<Apple>> feedToApplesMap = new HashMap<>();
for (final Apple Apple : AppleList) {
    final List<String> feedDocumentIds = Apple.getFeedDocumentIds();
    for (final String feedId : feedDocumentIds) {
        final List<Apple> AppleListForFeed = feedToApplesMap
                .getOrDefault(feedId, new ArrayList<>());
        AppleList.add(Apple);
        feedToApplesMap.put(feedId, AppleListForFeed);
    }
}
```

I am unable to use iterator to solve this ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: why would you want to do `AppleList.add(Apple);`?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full stack trace of the Exception.

Comment: A more Java 8-suited approach would be to use a `Stream` and `groupingBy()`. By doing this, you would likely get rid of all the nested loops and limit the possibility for bugs (such as the `add()` to the wrong list in your code).

Comment: Adhere to the naming conventions. This code is really hard to read.

Comment: Apparently, you want to add to `AppleListForFeed` instead of `AppleList`. In that case, simplify the entire loop body to `feedToApplesMap .computeIfAbsent(feedId, key -> new ArrayList<>() ) .add(Apple);`, so you don’t need another `put` operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @andbi that the question is due to a typo. But just for the exception, By doing so `for (final Apple Apple : AppleList)`  you are still using **Iterator** unintentionally, that's why here `AppleList.add(Apple);` will throw ConcurrentModificationException, you can do it like this to avoid using Iterator:

```
final Map<String, List<Apple>> feedToApplesMap = new HashMap<>();
int size = AppleList.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    final Apple Apple = AppList.get(i);
    final List<String> feedDocumentIds = Apple.getFeedDocumentIds();
    for (final String feedId : feedDocumentIds) {
        final List<Apple> AppleListForFeed = feedToApplesMap
                .getOrDefault(feedId, new ArrayList<>());
        AppleList.add(Apple);
        feedToApplesMap.put(feedId, AppleListForFeed);
    }
}
```

Please be aware that enhanced for-loop is just a syntatic sugar for for-loop with Iterator, the following two are the same:

```
    for (Iterator<T> i = c.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
 
    for (T t : c)
```

Here is the document: [The For-Each Loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're storing apples in a wrong place. Shouldn't it be

`AppleListForFeed.add(Apple)` instead of `AppleList.add(Apple)` ?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when we are iterating a list using for loop or for each and some elements are added in between during iterating so use iterator or iterating a list:

```
val iterator = yourList.iterator()
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        val currentItem = iterator.next()
    }
```

now add or delete any other element in your list during iterating.